# VSCode can't comment line in PowerShell file

Tags: visual-studio-code

In a JavaScript file it's easy comment single or multiple lines by pressing ctrl+/ or ctrl+k, ctrl+k. If I try the same commands in a PowerShell file, nothing happens. I am running version 0.10.0. Do I need to set up something special for PowerShell files?

Comment: Works for me though, can you try to run the commands from the command palette directly (Ctrl+Shift+P)?

Comment: I tried via keyboard shortcuts and ctrl+shift+p with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled VSCode, deleted the AppData folder and any other remnants I could find, and re-installed. Commenting in PowerShell worked again. When I updated the storage.json file to be in the insiders channel, commenting broke. [Insiders Channel](https://cmatskas.com/visual-studio-code-getting-insider-builds/)

Something with v0.10 has broken commenting for me.

**Update: This is an out-of-date question as this was during the early days. VS Code PowerShell commenting works fine in regular and insiders versions.**